# Parallel downloading of images for ImageMagick PHP

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, curl-multi

I'm running an Imagick script which downloads hundreds of images and processes them together in various ways. The script currently spends about 95% of its execution time downloading the images, and is getting them synchronously so clearly would benefit from fetching them asynchronously.

```
for ($i=0;$i<$quantity;$i++) {

  $a=$arranged[$i];
  $url  = $a->url;

  /* time new image operation */
    $download_time_start = getTime();
    $temp=new Imagick($url);
    $download_time_end = getTime();
    $download_time += ($download_time_end - $download_time_start);
  /* end time */
```

I am trying to find the optimal way of making the downloads occur in parallel. The application currently resides on AWS.

**Option 1:** Use something like curl_multi_exec to gather the images in parallel within the PHP script.

**Option 2:** Use something like Amazon's SQS and workers service to download the images, store them in S3 and then process them once complete.

Intuitively Option 1 feels quicker but more dangerous as a large number of large images could top out the available RAM for that instance. I'm also struggling to find any examples of anyone using curl_multi to fetch images in this way. Option 2 feels inefficient as the time taken to write and then read back all of the images between the instance and S3 may be significant.

Any advice appreciated

Comment: probably better if you just split the script up: one master script that splits off child scripts. each child fetches an image and then does the imagick stuff when the download completes.

Comment: I would just run a number of copies of the same script (if they won't interact and can work in concurrent mode). Just need to make a strategy, so different copies won't process the same resource. You can simply achieve that by adding a parameter to a script, like --copy=1 or --copy=2.

Comment: They will interact once all images are downloaded. Some of the processing actions mean that all images get merged into one at the end. For this reason I think running multiple scripts would be messy

Comment: Well, the problem with PHP and `curl_multi` is this `asynchrony`. In big projects these kind of things are usually formed as a client-job/queue-worker solution. So it totally makes sense to run multiple processes / workers for the tasks like yours. This may be useful as a reference: http://gearman.org/

Comment: You could try guzzle, which would let you make curl_multi calls that execute a callback for each successful response. http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-guzzle-send-asynchronous-requests